# OutputStream.flush() not committing response data to HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, json, http, servlets, jetty

I am using the jetty HTTPClient and ContentExchange to implement a proxy.  ContentExchange has several hook methods that can be overridden to execute code when certain pieces of the response are loaded.  My problem is with loading the response body from a jetty Buffer to the HttpServletResponse object returned to the client.  The response content is JSON, and shorter JSON is correctly exported to the client, but longer JSON does not show up in the response, and results in the following error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.  The documentation does not show any maximum length to the outputStream object, so I am unsure why the content would be cut off/not loading at all.

```
ContentExchange contentExchange = new ContentExchange() {

        ServletOutputStream outputStream;

        String contentString = "";

        @Override
        protected void onResponseStatus(Buffer version, int status, Buffer reason) throws IOException {
            super.onResponseStatus(version, status, reason);
            httpResponse.setStatus(status);
            remoteLRSRequest.setStatus(status);
            remoteLRSRequest.setResponse(reason.toString());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResponseHeader(Buffer name, Buffer value) throws IOException {
            super.onResponseHeader(name, value);
            httpResponse.setHeader(name.toString(), value.toString());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResponseContent(Buffer content) throws IOException {
            if (outputStream == null) {
                outputStream = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
            }
            content.writeTo(outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResponseComplete() throws IOException {
            outputStream.close();
            super.onResponseComplete();
        }
}
```

Note: When I step through this code in my debugger, I can see the entirety of the response content loaded into the outputStream.  However, it seems that flush() is not correctly committing the response data.

Comment: What version of Jetty HTTP Client?

Answer (score 0):

This was a misdiagnosis of the actual problem.  The response I was relaying contained a "Transfer-Endcoding: chunked" header that was causing problems.